# JavaScript piece executed or not executed if preceding script fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, jquery-events

I've just learned an important fact about the execution of Javascript in case of an error being thrown. Before I start making conclusions of this I'd better verify whether I am right.

Given an HTML page including 2 scripts:

```
<script src="script1.js" />
<script src="script2.js" />
```

script1:

```
doSomething();
```

script2:

```
doSomeOtherThing();
```

This effectively results in a single script being processed as one unit:

```
doSomething();
doSomeOtherThing();
```

In particular, if `doSomething` throws an error, the execution is broken. 'script2' is never being executed.

This is my **"Lesson 1"** - one might think since it is a separately included file it is not affected by script1. <strike>But it is.</strike> **=> see "late update" below**

---

Now, if we change script2 as follows (presuming we have jQuery included somewhere above):

```
$(document).ready({ doSomeOtherThing(); });
```

and place the script before script2:

```
<script src="script2.js" />
<script src="script1.js" />
```

The order of execution is effectively still 'doSomething()' followed (sometime) by 'doSomeOtherThing()'.

However it is executed in two "units":

- `doSomething` is executed early as part of the document's java script
- `doSomeOtherThing` is executed when the document.ready event is processed.

If `doSomeOtherThing` throws an exception, it will **not** break the second processing "unit".

(I refrain from using the term `thread` because I reckon that all script is usually executed by the same thread, or more precisely this may depend on the browser.)

So, my **Lession 2**: Even though a JavaScript error may prevent any subsequent scripts from executing, it does not stop the event loop.

---

**Conclusion 1**

`$(document).ready()` does a great job in defining chunks of JavaScript code that should be executed independent on any other scripts in succeeding.

Or, in other words: If you have a piece of JavaScript and want to make sure it gets executed even if other scripts fail, place it within a `$(document).ready()`.

This would be new to me in that I would only have used the event if the script depends on the document being fully loaded.

---

**Conclusion 2**

Taking it a step further it might be a good architecture decision to wrap *all* scripts within a `$(document).ready()` to make sure that all scripts are "queued" for execution. In the second example above, if `script2.js` was included *after* `script1.js` as in example 1:

```
<script src="script1.js" />
<script src="script2.js" />
```

An error in script1.js would prevent the `doSomeOtherThing()` from even being registered, because the `$(document).ready()` function would not be executed.

However, if script1.js used `$(document).ready()`, too, that would not happen:

```
$(document).ready(function() { doSomething(); });
$(document).ready(function() { doSomeOtherThing(); });
```

Both lines would be executed. Then later the event loop would execute `doSomething` which would break, but `doSomeOtherThing` would not be affected.

One more reason to do so would be that the thread rendering the page can return as soon as possible, and the event loop can be used to trigger the code execution.

---

**Critique / Questions:**

- Was I mistaken?
- What reasons are there that make it necessary to execute a piece of code *immediately*, i.e. not wrapping it into the event?
- Would it impact performance significantly?
- Is there another/better way to achieve the same rather than using the document ready event?
- Can the execution order of scripts be defined if all scripts just register their code as an event handler? Are the event handlers executed in the order they were registered?

Looking forward to any helpful comments!

**Late Update:**

Like Briguy37 pointed out correctly, my observation must have been wrong in the first place. ("Was I mistaken - yes!"). Taking his simple example I can reproduce that in all major browsers and even in IE8, script2 is executed even if script1 throws an error.

Still @Marcello's great answer helps get some insight in the concepts of execution stacks etc. It just seems that each of the two scripts is executed in a separate execution stack.

Comment: Thanks for all your findings. Very very useful to read +1

Comment: @Beto - thank you for the upvote. Unfortunately my observation was proven wrong. I updated my question and the accepted answer now. Feel free to retire the upvote.

Comment: Hi @chiccodoro! I read your post as a start then I read all the answers. Not all your findings were wrong, and it help me somehow to understand better the other answers that are more technical. So thanks anyway!

Comment: @Beto, good to hear that!

Comment: I got the same issue. My second ready() did not run because of the first one.   $(document).ready(//error in first). $(document).ready(//second could not be executed)

Comment: @Girish - I hope you get your issues fixed! However, what you describe does not match what my question said. I was saying that using $(document).ready(...) would solve the issue of a second script not being executed. You have a case where it does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first assumption that they run as one script is incorrect.  Script2 will still execute even if Script1 throws an error.  For a simple test, implement the following file structure:

```
-anyFolder
--test.html
--test.js
--test2.js
```

The contents of test.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"></script>
   </head>
</html>
```

The contents of test.js:

```
console.log('test before');
throw('foo');
console.log('test after');
```

The contents of test2.js:

```
console.log('test 2');
```

The output when you open test.html (in the console):

```
test before test.js:1
Uncaught foo test.js:2
test 2
```

From this test, you can see that test2.js still runs even though test.js throws an error.  However, test.js stops executing after it runs into the error.

Comment: That's interesting. It either means that I erred when observing the complete opposite of your observation in my code, or it may be dependent on the browser? I'll have to take a closer look and verify it again.

Comment: @chiccodoro:  Ok, please let us know if you find different functionality somewhere.  I've tried in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox with the same results in each.

Comment: done, and exactly like you said: script2 is executed (FF, IE9). I verified the same behavior when I include the tags in the bottom of the body. But for the rather complex page I was taking my conclusions from there is a script being separately included which is not executed if the script included before fails. Strange...

Comment: Can anyone confirm if IE8 is the exception? My code throws an error but every browser except IE8 proceeds with the rest of the scripts.

Comment: @HellaMedusa, I have tested with IE8 and I get the same result as Briguy37 reports... I must have erred back then in the very first observation.

Answer (score 16):

The way JS handles errors, depends on the way JS is processing the script. It has nothing (or little) to do with threads. Therefor you have to first think about how JS works through your code.

First of all JS will readin every script file/block sequently (at this point your code is just seen as text).

Than JS starts interpreting that textblocks and compiling them into executable code. If an syntax error is found, JS stops compiling and goes on to the next script. In this process JS handles every script blocks/files as separated entity, that's why an syntax errors in script 1 does not necessarily break the execution of script 2.  The code will be interpreted and compiled, but not executed at this point, so a `throw new Error` command wouldn't break the execution.

After all script files/blocks are compiled, JS goes through the code (starting with the first code file/block in your code) and building up a so called execution stack (function a calls function b calls function d and c....) and executing it in the given order. If at any point a processing error occurs or is thrown programmatically (`throw new Error('fail')`) the whole execution of that stack is stopped and JS goes back to the beginning to the beginning of that stack and starts with the execution of the next possible stack.

That said, the reason that your onload function is still executed after an error in script1.js, does not happen because of a new thread or something, it's simply because an event builds up a separate execution stack, JS can jump to, after the error in the previous execution stack happend.

Coming to your questions:

> What reasons are there that make it necessary to execute a piece of code immediately, i.e. not wrapping it into the event?

I would advice you to have no "immediatly" called code in your web-application at all. The best practice is to have a single point of entrance in your application that is called inside of an onload event

```
$(document).ready(function () {App.init()});
```

This however has nothing to do with error handling or such. Error handling itself should definitely be done inside your code with either conditionals `if(typeof myValue !== 'undefined')` or try/catch/finally blocks, where you might expect potential errors. This also gives you the opportunity to try a second way inside of the catch block or gracefully handle the error in finally.

If you can build up your application event driven (not for error handling reasons of course), do so. JS is an event driven language and you can get the most out of it, when writing event driven code...

> Would it impact performance significantly?

An event driven approach would IMHO make your application perform even better and make it more solid at the same time. Event driven code can help you to reduce the amount of internal processing logic, you just have to get into it.

> Is there another/better way to achieve the same rather than using the document ready event?

As before mentioned: try/catch/finally

> Can the execution order of scripts be defined if all scripts just register their code as an event handler? Are the event handlers executed in the order they were registered?

If you register the same event on the same object, the order is preserved.

Comment: Thanks, Marcello! As for the "sub-chains" - can you elaborate on them? How do I create a sub-chain that is even executed if the preceeding sub-chain throws an exception? Are you referring to using "try-catch"?

Comment: As for the performance - this confirms what I would be thinking, too, although, a simple piece of code executed with the overhead of registering and processing an event as opposed to doing it directly probably adds some extra time for execution - but it can be done asynchronously (or at least later) in turn

Comment: @chiccodoro I had to correct some parts, since they were misleading. First it's not a exec chain it's a stack. Second there are only 3 ways to build a "sub" or detached stack: setTimeout, Events and eval, it does not depend on your code layout as my answer implied. Here's a good link about stacks in JS: http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about syntax errors, but you can use `try {} catch(e) {}` to catch the errors and keep the rest of the code running.

**Will NOT run untill the end**

```
var json = '{"name:"John"'; // Notice the missing curly bracket }

// This probably will throw an error, if the string is buggy
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert('This will NOT run');
```

**Will run untill the end**

```
var json = '{"name:"John"'; // Notice the missing curly bracket }

// But like this you can catch errors
try {
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
} catch (e) {
  // Do or don'
}

alert('This will run');
```

**UPDATE**

I just wanted to show how to make sure that the rest of the code gets executed in case the error occurs.

> What reasons are there that make it necessary to execute a piece of
>   code immediately, i.e. not wrapping it into the event?

Performance. Every such event fills up the event queue. Not that it will hurt much, but it's just not necessary... Why to do some work later, if it can be done right now? For example - browser detection and stuff.

> Would it impact performance significantly?

If you are doing this many times per second, then yes.

> Is there another/better way to achieve the same rather than using the
>   document ready event?

Yes. See above example.

> Can the execution order of scripts be defined if all scripts just
>   register their code as an event handler? Are the event handlers
>   executed in the order they were registered?

Yes, I'm pretty sure that they are.

Comment: Thanks. I am presuming that the potential errors of either piece of code are not known in advance. Generally swalling the erros would IMHO not be a good idea. I prefer to make them bubble up until they get reported into the javascript console of the browser.

Comment: Syntax errors are a different story though. I guess they would not affect any other subsequent script files.

Comment: @chiccodoro You could pass the error to the console by `console.log(e)`. But this `try - catch` is the way how to do it. Don't listent to me, jQuery does the same! Read the source - you will see.

Comment: Point taken, although I generally consider swalling unknown errors a "bad smell". `console` is not supported by all browsers, is it?

Comment: @chiccodoro Simply use this as universal console! https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/js/plugins.js